# How to setup nested routing for a self referencing controller in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, self-reference

I have a Categories controller setup as a self referencing controller to give me the ability to create a series of sub categories. However, I am completely lost on how I would go about setting up routing in my application so I could have urls such as http://www.example.com/category/subcategory/product/

I currently have my categories routing set up as such

```
resources :categories, except: :index, :path => '/'
```

and my model set up as

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id", :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key=>"parent_id"
end
```

However, I am completely stumped as to where I would start with such a task after reading through the Rails guide to routing and searching elsewhere for a solution. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: it's not entirely clear what you want. in the example URL, is 'product' the name of a subcategory? or is it intended to list the products in some subcategory? if it's the latter, how is the subcategory/category identified in that URL?

Comment: I haven't actually created the products model / controller yet hence why it is currently missing from the code. So you would be otherwise correct in assume that for now the URL would ideally be just  http://www.example.com/category/subcategory/

Comment: that still doesn't really answer my question. in your example URL are "category" and "subcategory" place words for what would actually be the names of a category and subcategory, or something? i.e. example.com/jewellery/necklaces ? otherwise, how are the category and subcategory identified?

Comment: Sorry yes they are place words, I was hoping to eventually use something like the friendly_id gem to handle that but would be happy with just the [id] values for now. So example.com/4/6 where 4 is a category and 6 is a subcategory of 4

Answer (score 2):

To have nested routes, you need to wrap the nested route in a `do end` block :

```
resources :categories, except: :index, :path => '/' do
  resources :subcategories do
    resources :products
  end
end
```

As for the *self referencing* part,why don't you create a `subcategories` controller and model and associate it to the `category` model? So you get the following URL :

```
http://example.com/categories/1/subcategories/3/products
```

Having separate models will give you access to some useful methods :

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories

class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
```

Now, you can see all the subcategories that belong to a category, the category to which a subcategory belongs and many more.

```
Category.find(1).subcategories
Subcategory.find(1).category
```

Checkout [Active Record Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that the only way to get the desired URL is to create a separate model & controller for a subcategory?

Comment: It might not be the only way, but from my experience with Rails, it is the simplest way. I will update my answer in a moment.

Comment: This doesn't help if for example you have a model that could be anywhere from 2 to n levels deep. Obviously it's not good practice to put 6 or 7 subcategories in the URL but 3 would be fine I think.